# Background threads and absl::Notifications in TensorFlow custom-ops

Tags: tensorflow

I am adding a custom op to TensorFlow that essentially needs to launch and wait on a background thread, but seem to have run into a deadlock issue.

This is warned against in the TensorFlow documentation as it might prevent other ops from being executed (see tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h), and `AsyncOpKernel` is likely a better match for the task, yet I would like to understand why only option B and C below seem to work, with option A apparently resulting in a deadlock.

Running the same code outside TensorFlow gives the behaviour I expected, leading me to believe this is somehow related to the mix between absl and TensorFlow.

```cpp
class AsyncTestOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit AsyncTestOp(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override {

    absl::Notification notification;

    std::thread thread(
      [](absl::Notification* notification) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        notification->Notify();
      },
      &notification);

    // Option A: doesn't work
    notification.WaitForNotification();

    // Option B: works
    // while (!notification.HasBeenNotified()) {
    //   notification.WaitForNotificationWithTimeout(absl::Milliseconds(100));
    // }

    // Option C: works
    // while (!notification.HasBeenNotified()) {
    //   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    // }

    thread.join();
  }
};
```